# Why do I get a handler() error from the Python Flickr API

Tags: python, flickr

Sample code, where photo_id is an id string and flickr a successfully authenticated Flickr API session:

```
rsp = flickr.photos_getInfo(photo_id)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: handler() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)
```

http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getInfo.html says that photos_getInfo takes (at least) one argument, so what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to photos_getInfo needs to use a keyword argument, like this:

```
rsp = flickr.photos_getInfo(photo_id = photo_id)
```